# JavaScript permutations function - why isn't this working?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

I'm trying to write a function in JavaScript to generate an array of permutations of a given array by porting the [code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) in the Python documentation for itertools.permutations. (I am aware that the actual function is written in C) This is what I have, and it outputs an array with the correct length - n!/(n-r)!, n being the length of the array - but each element is just the original array, not rearranged. I'd appreciate a fresh pair of eyes on my code, as I'm stumped:

```
function permutations(array, r) {
    if (r === undefined) r = array.length;
    if (r > array.length) return;
    var indices = range(array.length);
    var cycles = range(array.length, array.length - r, -1);
    var result = [[]];
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        result[0].push(array[i]);
    }
    while (1) {
        var exhausted = true;
        for (var i = r - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            cycles[i] -= 1;
            if (cycles[i] == 0) {
                indices = indices.slice(0, i).concat(
                    indices.slice(i + 1)
                ).concat([indices[i]]);
                cycles[i] = array.length - i;
            }
            else {
                var j = cycles[i];
                swap(indices, i, indices.length - j);
                var p = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                    p.push(array[i]);
                }
                result.push(p);
                exhausted = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (exhausted) break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The closest equivalent would probably be a generator `function*` and using the `yield` keyword similar to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python code has (near the bottom):

```
yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
```

You translated that to:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                p.push(array[i]);
            }
            result.push(p);
```

But it should be:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                p.push(array[indices[i]]);
            }
            result.push(p);
```

Without that, `indices` is never used, which should be a clue.